# Convert excel or csv to list or dictionary, or word doc to list in python

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, dictionary

I want my end-result to be a dictionary like the below.

`mydict = {0:'term1', 1:'term2',...'159:'term160'}`

I have a csv that has a single column of data, with a few words in each cell of the column's single row.

So far none of the suggestions I've found on here have helped. The closest I came was where one formula created multiple ordered dictionaries that from my single column created dictionaries like the below:

```
{['term1'], ['term2']}
{['term1'], ['term3']}
{['term1'], ['term4']}
```

So, instead of doing that, I thought I would just create a list from the column. When using the code below, rather that getting something like `['term1', 'term2', 'term3',...'term160']`, I instead received `[['term1'],['term2'],...['term160']]`, which when combined with `my_list2 = list(range(0, 160))` via `my_dict = dict.fromkeys(my_list_numbers, my_list_terms)`, printed out a dictionary of each number in the range matched with the entirety of the `[['term1'],['term2'],...['term160']]`

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)
```

I just want either a dictionary or a list of strings that I can turn into a dictionary so that I don't have to type out multiple dictionaries of 100+ pairs each. I've been googling and experimenting for over an hour. I'm relatively new to code, but I feel like it shouldn't be this hard to extract a list of strings from an excel, csv, word, or text doc. Or simply format that from a list that I paste into the cell, even.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample csv data and corresponding desired output data. Thanks.

Comment: @Argileon, assuming your data is single column and that you're considering the output as list, try the following `{idx:value[0] for idx, value in enumerate(data)}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a data in file temp.csv as follows:

```
this_is_r1
this_is_r2
this_is_r3
this_is_r4
```

You can write your code as:

```
import os
os.chdir("/home/username/Downloads")

res= dict()

with open("temp.csv", "r") as f:
    for k,x in enumerate(f):
        res[k] = x.replace("\n","")

print(res)
```

The output is:

```
{0: 'this_is_r1', 1: 'this_is_r2', 2: 'this_is_r3', 3: 'this_is_r4', 4: 'this_is_r5', 5: 'this_is_r6'}
```

As suggested by Miguel Trejo, you can also use dictionary comprehension as:

```
with open("temp.csv", "r") as f:
    res={k:x.replace("\n","") for k,x in enumerate(f)}

print(res)
```